# In confirmatory factor analysis, what is the notation for the modification index?

Tags: structural-equation-modeling, notation, confirmatory-factor

What symbol or abbreviation can we use to refer to the modification index? Say you were writing an article about a CFA that was performed and inside of the article you want to list several modification indices. What symbol is used to represent them? I think what would make sense is either χ<sup>2</sup><sub>Δ</sub> or MI, but I can't find this as an official guideline anywhere. So I was wondering which symbol is usually used to represent these indices?

Comment: I don't think there's a standard. MI is fine. It's also the estimated change in chi-square, so you could use delta chi-square, but it's not the actual change in chi-square, so I wouldn't.

Comment: Given its relationship with Lagrange Multipliers, $\lambda$ could also be an option, depending on context.